# Change Currency Symbol in Switcher & at Products

Tags: currency, switcher

It's very strange to me that somehow I can nowhere find perfectly described how to change these things

How to get a currency symbol here like: €, $ and so forth

[image]

How to change this Currency Title? So I can delete those US before the $

[image]

Appreciate everyone's Help

-1-

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 1, you can find currency symbols configuration at *Admin > System > Manage currency > Currency symbols*

Get more display currency: Go to *System > Configuration > General > Currency setup*, choose display currency you want in **Allowed currencies**, don't forget setup currency rate for each.